# Typo3 and Frontend Variable in cache

Tags: caching, typo3

I have typo3 11.5.25.
I want to store in cache a variable so i tried to use:
TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\VariableFrontend class

I tried this:

```
$backend = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\FrontendInterface::getBackend();
$cache = new VariableFrontend('VariableFrontend', $backend);
$cache->set("exampleIdentifier","nomebariabile",array("tag-sede"),10000);
```

I got this error:

```
Cannot call abstract method TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\Frontend\FrontendInterface::getBackend()
```

There are some things I don't know, how can I store a variable in cache?

Comment: Please read the docs to see how the [caching framework](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/CachingFramework/Index.html) should be used.

Comment: What is your use case? I am not so sure you are trying to use the right tool...

Comment: @MathiasBrodala it is for page caching, it is not a good idea to store only a variable in cache e use it when i want?

Comment: @JulianHofmann I'm not sure to use the correct tool. I want to store a variable in cache e use it when i want. It si possible?

Comment: What kind of variable? Where come sit from? For which use do you need it in the FE?.... Cache is not a kind of storage. Maybe, TYPO3s System registry could be a solution (https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SystemRegistry/Index.html). But without some more details, it's hard to point you anywhere.

Comment: I should put somewhere an array of cities from a web service to populate a select form. If I contacted it once I would not contact him again for all users that browse the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

In my **ext_localconf.php**

```
if( !isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] ['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$extensionKey] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] ['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$extensionKey] = array();
    }

    if( !isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] ['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$extensionKey]['frontend'] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] ['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$extensionKey]['frontend'] = 'TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\Frontend\\VariableFrontend' ;
    }

    if( !isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] ['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$extensionKey]['options'] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] ['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$extensionKey]['options'] = array('defaultLifetime' => 3600);
    }
    if( !isset($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] ['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$extensionKey]['groups'] ) ) {
        $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS'] ['SYS']['caching']['cacheConfigurations'][$extensionKey]['groups'] = array('pages');
    }
```

**In controller:**

```
$cacheIdentifier = 'identifier';

$this->cacheInstance = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Cache\\CacheManager')->getCache('extname');
if ( $this->cacheInstance->has($cacheIdentifier))
{
  // Cache available
  $aResult = $this->cacheInstance->get($cacheIdentifier);
}
else
{
   $this->cacheInstance->set($cacheIdentifier, array('myvariable'=>'value'), array('mytag'));
}
```

All data is stored in my mysql tables:

```
cache_myext_tags
cache_myext
```

Hope this may help